# PHP return the nth row of a html table with dom

Tags: php, html, dom, html-table

I'm trying to use the simplehtmldom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to print out the nth row of a table. Currently nothing happens, is there anything else I need to do?

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.masjid-umar.org/downloads/timetable_apr.htm');
$ret = $html->find('tr', 9);
echo $ret;
?>
```

Comment: I was able to get output from your code with no changes.

<tr class=xl9018399 height=29 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:21.95pt'>    <td height=29 class=xl8618399 style='height:21.95pt;border-top:none'>TUE</td>    <td class=xl8618399 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>1</td>

Comment: Thank you. I will try again on a different machine. Out of curiosity, does the output end with "1</td>" or is the stackoverflow comment system limiting the characters?

Comment: That was the character limit for a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming row 9 is the row for TUE, you can also do this with PHP's inbuilt DOMDocument, which would save some memory and parsing time and not rely on a 3rd party script.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.masjid-umar.org/downloads/timetable_apr.htm');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//TUE 1 1 4.37 6.39 1.08 5.35 9.18 6.00 1.30 6.30 7.42 9.40                 
echo '
<table>
    <tr>';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table) {
    echo innerHTML($table->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(9));
}
echo '
    </tr>
</table>';

function innerHTML($current){
    $ret = "";
    $nodes = @$current->childNodes;
    if(!empty($nodes)){
        foreach($nodes as $v){
            $tmp = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp->appendChild($tmp->importNode($v, true));
            $ret .= $tmp->saveHTML();
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return;
}
?>
```

Your also want to look into caching the result for a day as the site is slooow ;p

Answer (score 1):

0 is the first row, so 8 would be the ninth:

```
$ret = $html->find('tr', 8);
```