# PHP Simple HTML DOM - How to find the table by a particular value in TD?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

My table looks like,

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong>NPA/Area Code:</strong></td>
<td><a href="/area-code/area-code-229.asp">229</a></td>
<td><strong>NXX Use Type:</strong></td>
<td>LANDLINE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>NXX/Prefix:</strong></td>
<td>428</td>
<td><strong>NXX Intro Version:</strong></td>
<td>2000-10-31</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There are so many tables with no `id` or `class`, so finding the one I want is so hard. I am thinking about to use the text in the `td` to select the `table`. Is that possible? Because the site I want to scrape data from is coded to be this way. I am unsure how to manipulate the code with Simple HTML DOM, to select this table and then select the text within the `td`. I know how to extract the value inside `td`, so the question is how to select this particular table that I want. The link I want to scrape data is, [scrape source](http://www.area-codes.com/exchange/exchange.asp?npa=229&nxx=428)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to parse anyway?

Comment: jQuery lets you do: `$('table:has(td:contains("LANDLINE"))')` - simple can't do that but [this one can](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/files/?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a marker for that table, since your trying to get the table below `AreaCode/Prefix 229-428 Details`, then use that and then point to the next sibling which is that particular table that you want. Example:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.area-codes.com/exchange/exchange.asp?npa=229&nxx=428');
$table = null;
$needle = 'AreaCode/Prefix 229-428 Details';
foreach($html->find('h3') as $marker) {
    if($marker->innertext == $needle) {
        $table = $marker->next_sibling();
        break;
    }
}

$data = array();
if($table) {
    foreach($table->children() as $k => $tr) {
        foreach($tr->children as $td) {
            $data[$k][] = $td->innertext;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for but didn't have the ability to translate it into the code :)

Comment: @Eshwar yes, since you can't just directly point out so many tables because they are so many (and complicated), this way is much better. im glad this helped

Comment: yeah, Thanks again, this taught me about markers, I am so glad and thankful for that :)

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316991/php-return-the-nth-row-of-a-html-table-with-dom) might be helpful.

Essentially, you can get the nth element as such:

```
$table = $html->find('table', 3);
```

So long as the number of tables doesn't change you can extend that to do what you want.

Comment: There are nested tables. So the count messes up.